# Как сделать запрос и сразу вывести его на экран?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Я делаю запрос

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO ...
```

Он создает новую строчку, как мне сразу из этой строчки подцепить столбец?

Comment: Использовать multi-query.

Answer (score 1):

```
const pquery = (sql, args)  => { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
         connection.query(sql, args, (err, res)=>{
              if (err){
                 return reject(err)
              }
              resolve(res)
         })
    })
}

async function insertAndLog(tableName, data){
    const { insertId } = await pquery("INSERT INTO ?? SET ?", [tableName, 
    data])
    const data = await pquery("SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE id = ?", [tableName, 
    insertId])
    console.log(data)
    return data;
}

insertAndLog('yourTable', {a:1, b:2}) //Твои название таблицы и данные
```